# Give an example of algorithm that is output sensitive, but not input sensitive

Tags: algorithm

Could this be an example ?

1. x = randomNumber()
2. If x < 100 add x to the list and go to step 1.
3. Print list

Comment: What does "output sensitive" mean here?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Output-sensitive_algorithm

Comment: You don't necessarily need an algorithm that takes no input at all. If the runtime depends on the "content" of the input rather than the size of the input, that would be output-sensitive as well; e.g. `myFunc(n) {for (i=0 to n) {print "Hello World!"}}` always takes 1 integer as input. Or e.g. finding whether a number is a prime, which takes x number of steps, depending on the specific value.

Comment: The algorithm you described above doesn't seem to have a step for when it stops.  Can you also add this to your question?

Comment: Yes, I think this is an example.

Answer (score 0):

Wikipedia says: "An output-sensitive algorithm is an algorithm whose running time depends on the size of the output." So, that's pretty easy:

1. Choose a random number in some range, say 10-1000.
2. Output that many dots.

The more dots, the longer it takes for your program to run. To make it more dramatic, you can pause for a second between dots.

Your example works too, since the longer the program runs (when the numbers happen to be small), the larger the output will be.